# Method Passing ViewModel vs Passing Bound Variables

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a `ComboBox` bound to a ViewModel `string` `Quality_SelectedItem`.

And I have a Method named Quality, which inside accesses the value of the SelectedItem in an `if` statement.

I have two ways of accessing the value, by passing the ViewModel through the Method, or by passing the `string` `Quality_SelectedItem`.

Which way should I be using it and which performs faster?

---

#### XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboQuality" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Quality_Items}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Quality_SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="0,2,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="105" 
          Height="22"/>
```

#### ViewModel Class

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

    // Quality Selected Item
    private string _Quality_SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public string Quality_SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _Quality_SelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (_Quality_SelectedItem == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _Quality_SelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Quality_SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    ...
```

---

#### Example 1 - Passing ViewModel

In the Quality Method, I access `vm.Quality_SelectedItem` directly from the `if` statement.

```
public ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();

// MainWindow
public MainWindow() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = vm;

    // Quality Method
    Quality(vm); // <---
}


// Quality Method
public static void Quality(ViewModel vm) 
{
    if (vm.Quality_SelectedItem == "High") 
    {
        // do something
    }
    else if (vm.Quality_SelectedItem == "Low") 
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

---

#### Example 2 - Passing String SelectedItem

I pass `vm.Quality_SelectedItem` through the Quality Method and give it the `string` name `quality`.

```
public ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();

// MainWindow
public MainWindow() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = vm;

    // Quality Method
    Quality(vm.Quality_SelectedItem); // <---
}


// Quality Method
public static void Quality(string quality) 
{
    if (quality == "High") 
    {
        // do something
    }
    else if (quality == "Low") 
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides that it is totally irrelevant which method you use, the term "Method Constructor" is pointless. A method has no constructor. You just pass arguments or parameters to a method call.

Comment: Thanks I will change the title.

Comment: Note that you could as well use a non-static method that directly accesses the `vm` member, like `private void Quality() { ... }`

Comment: I forgot to mention, I also use it in other static methods in other classes, and have to pass `ViewModel vm` for the method to see it.

Comment: How are the combobx and vm wired up? Is there a need to bring the extra complexity or can you simply expose a property in the MainWindow and access it directly?

Comment: Both methods are good and useful. In given context second method has a slight advantage (less coupling). As to *"which performs faster"*, make sure to [read about horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).. because they are fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you should make your code as simple as possible. Remember the KISS principle. This also plays well with SOLID ("simple" is a good way to achieve Single responsibility and Interface segregation).

Avoid reaching into one object to get another.

If you need only a `string` value in the method, only pass that `string` value. Don't force your method to dig into object hierarchies and dependencies to get that value.

If the method needs to *modify* a `string` property value, then pass the object where to modify the property.

From the performance point of view, you will not notice any change. Accessing an object by-reference is a very cheap operation. (Unless you're implementing loops with billions of iterations.)

From the design point of view, keeping the things simple makes your code SOLID and easily allows re-usage.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is `//do something`.

- If you have to handle/interact your `viewmodel`-object, then pass
  `viewmodel` as parameter
- otherwise use a string for less dependencies and possibility of common use.
- If you have your viewmodel as singleton, then it doesn't matter which way you go.

Comment: If the Method is a `void`, I usually have the `// do something` change the value of a public `int` or `string` variable. If the Method is a `String`, I might have it `return` a value.